# Need to calc start and end date from single effective date

Tags: sql, date

I am trying to write SQL to calculate the start and end date from a single date called effective date for each item.  Below is a idea of how my data looks.  There are times when the last effective date for an item will be in the past so I want the end date for that to be a year from today.  The other two items in the table example have effective dates in the future so no need to create and end date of a year from today.

[image]

I have tried a few ways but always run into bad data.  Below is an example of my query and the bad results

```
select distinct tb1.itemid,tb1.EffectiveDate as startdate
, case 
when dateadd(d,-1,tb2.EffectiveDate) < getdate() 
or tb2.EffectiveDate is  null
then getdate() +365 
else dateadd(d,-1,tb2.EffectiveDate) 
end as enddate
from #test tb1

left join #test as tb2 on (tb2.EffectiveDate > tb1.EffectiveDate 
   or tb2.effectivedate is null) and tb2.itemid = tb1.itemid

left join #test tb3 on (tb1.EffectiveDate < tb3.EffectiveDate 
  andtb3.EffectiveDate <tb2.EffectiveDate or tb2.effectivedate is null) 
  and tb1.itemid = tb3.itemid

left join #test tb4 on tb1.effectivedate = tb4.effectivedate \
  and tb1.itemid = tb4.itemid

where tb1.itemID in (62741,62740, 65350)
```

Results - there is an extra line for 62740
[Bad Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Ffn.jpg)

I expect to see below since the first two items have a future end date no need to create an end date of today + 365 but the last one only has one effective date so we have to calculate the end date.

[image]

Comment: What do you want Start Date to be? Also, please copy the table into your question.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the results you are expecting from the query?

Comment: Answers below are all valid, but I have a question about  when an item with 3 or more entries.   Assume a ItemID has 4 dates A,B,C,D.   Would A > B and then B > C and then C > D (or 3) rows be the desired result.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Yes, but **which** DBMS? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? SQL Server?

Comment: What are your expectations? I answered assuming the above output is what you wanted.

Comment: is it possible that for the same Item there are equal EffectiveDate?what to do in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've read your question correctly. If you could provide your expected output it would help a lot.

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (itemID int, EffectiveDate date)
INSERT INTO #TestData (itemID, EffectiveDate)
VALUES
(62741,'2016-06-25')
,(62741,'2016-06-04')
,(62740,'2016-07-09')
,(62740,'2016-06-25')
,(62740,'2016-06-04')
,(65350,'2016-05-28')
```

Query

```
SELECT
a.itemID
,MIN(a.EffectiveDate) StartDate
,MAX(CASE WHEN b.MaxDate > GETDATE() THEN b.MaxDate ELSE CONVERT(date,DATEADD(yy,1,GETDATE())) END) EndDate
FROM #TestData a
JOIN (SELECT itemID, MAX(EffectiveDate) MaxDate FROM #TestData GROUP BY itemID) b
ON a.itemID = b.itemID
GROUP BY a.itemID
```

Result

```
itemID  StartDate   EndDate
62740   2016-06-04  2016-07-09
62741   2016-06-04  2016-06-25
65350   2016-05-28  2017-06-24
```

Comment: the only problem with the results is it does not account for item 62740 and thh effective date of 6/25/2016

Comment: where's your date 6/2/2016 coming from? that's not in the sample data you've given

Comment: 62740 has 3 effective dates listed

Comment: and none of them are 6/2/2016

Comment: Its 6/25/2016 not sure where you are seeing 6/2/2016.

Comment: your expected output, row 2 = 62740 - 06/02/2016 - 06/25/2016

Comment: @Joe I still can't work out if you're expecting two entries for itemID = 62740 or not. I think you don't want this as you refer to it as bad data. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT itemid
      ,effective_date AS "Start"
       ,(SELECT MIN(effective_date)
          FROM effective_date_tbl
         WHERE effective_date > edt.effective_date
           AND itemid = edt.itemid) AS "End"
  FROM effective_date_tbl edt
 WHERE effective_date <
       (SELECT MAX(effective_date) FROM effective_date_tbl WHERE itemid = edt.itemid)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT itemid
       ,effective_date AS "Start"
       ,(SYSDATE + 365) AS "End"
 FROM effective_date_tbl edt
 WHERE 1 =  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM effective_date_table WHERE itemid = edt.itemid )      
 ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: @Joe I need the UNION ALL clause to handle the case on 1 effective date

Answer (score 0):

I did this exercise for Items that have multiple EffectiveDate in the table

you can create this view

```
CREATE view [VW_TESTDATA] 
AS ( SELECT * FROM  
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Item,CONVERT(datetime,EffectiveDate,110)) AS ID, Item, DATA
FROM MyTable ) AS Q
)
```

so use a select to compare the same Item

```
select * from [VW_TESTDATA] as A inner join [VW_TESTDATA] as B on A.Item = B.Item and A.id = B.id-1
```

in this way you always minor and major Date

I did not understand how to handle dates with only one Item  , but it seems the simplest thing and can be added to this query with a UNION ALL, because the view not cover individual Item

You also need to figure out how to deal with Item with two equal EffectiveDate

Answer (score -1):

you should use the case when statement.. 
***[wrong query because a misunderstand of the requirements]***

```
SELECT 
       ItemID AS Item,
       StartDate,
       CASE WHEN EndDate < Sysdate THEN Sysdate + 365 ELSE EndDate END AS EndDate 
FROM 
(
  SELECT tabStartDate.ItemID, tabStartDate.EffectiveDate AS StartDate, tabEndDate.EffectiveDate AS EndDate
  FROM TableItems tabStartDate
  JOIN TableItems tabEndDate on tabStartDate.ItemID = tabEndDate.ItemID 
) TableDatesPerItem
WHERE StartDate < EndDate
```

***update after clarifications in the OP and some comments*** 

I found a solution quite portable, because it doesn't make use of partioning but endorses on a sort of indexing rule that make to correspond the dates of each item with others with the same id, in order of time's succession.

The portability is obviously related to the "difficult" part of query, while row numbering mechanism and conversion go adapted, but I think that it isn't a problem.

I sended a version for MySql that it can try on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/917ac/1)..

> **Table**

```
CREATE TABLE ITEMS 
      (`ItemID` int, `EffectiveDate` Date);

INSERT INTO ITEMS
      (`ItemID`, `EffectiveDate`)
VALUES
  (62741, DATE(20160625)),
  (62741, DATE(20160604)),
  (62740, DATE(20160709)),
  (62740, DATE(20160625)),
  (62740, DATE(20160604)),
  (62750, DATE(20160528))
;
```

> **Query**

```
SELECT 
     RESULT.ItemID AS ItemID, 
     DATE_FORMAT(RESULT.StartDate,'%m/%d/%Y') AS StartDate, 
     CASE WHEN RESULT.EndDate < CURRENT_DATE
      THEN DATE_FORMAT((CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 365 DAY),'%m/%d/%Y') 
      ELSE DATE_FORMAT(RESULT.EndDate,'%m/%d/%Y') 
     END AS EndDate
FROM
(
   SELECT 
     tabStartDate.ItemID AS ItemID, 
     tabStartDate.StartDate AS StartDate, 
     tabEndDate.EndDate
     ,tabStartDate.IDX,
     tabEndDate.IDX AS IDX2
     FROM
     (
      SELECT 
         tabStartDateIDX.ItemID AS ItemID, 
         tabStartDateIDX.EffectiveDate AS StartDate,
         @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS IDX
      FROM ITEMS AS tabStartDateIDX
      ORDER BY tabStartDateIDX.ItemID,  tabStartDateIDX.EffectiveDate
     )AS tabStartDate 
     JOIN
     (
       SELECT 
         tabEndDateIDX.ItemID AS ItemID, 
         tabEndDateIDX.EffectiveDate AS EndDate,
         @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS IDX
       FROM ITEMS AS tabEndDateIDX 
       ORDER BY tabEndDateIDX.ItemID, tabEndDateIDX.EffectiveDate
      )AS tabEndDate
      ON tabStartDate.ItemID = tabEndDate.ItemID AND (tabEndDate.IDX - tabStartDate.IDX = ((select count(*) from ITEMS)+1) )
     ,(SELECT @rownum:=0) r
  UNION
  (
    SELECT 
       tabStartDateSingleItem.ItemID AS ItemID, 
       tabStartDateSingleItem.EffectiveDate AS StartDate,
       tabStartDateSingleItem.EffectiveDate AS EndDate
       ,0 AS IDX,0 AS IDX2
     FROM ITEMS AS tabStartDateSingleItem
    Group By tabStartDateSingleItem.ItemID
    HAVING  Count(tabStartDateSingleItem.ItemID) = 1
  )
) AS RESULT
;
```

Comment: I'm sorry.. I misunderstand the problem..

however I found a solution quite portable, because don't make use of partions but endorse on a sort of indexing rule that make to correspond the dates of item in order of time's succession.
The portabilitu obviusly it is related to the "diffucult" part of query, the rownum mechanism and converison go adapted but it isn't a problem.

I send a version that work on test tables builded at fly in the query, it can be tested on Sql Fiddle.. 

the query it is in the upon answer field under a update labeled section